# App is crashing while geofencing applied with circular region

Tags: ios, swift, core-location, geofencing

I am creating an application for user tracking through beacons, and while app is in terminated state, I am using geofencing for tracking the user for circular region.

I am creating a circular region and did enter, did exit delegates are running correctly. But after that app get crashed.

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CLCircularRegion major]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x608000010470'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e29bb0b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010dcbb141 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e30b134 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e222840 ___forwarding___ + 1024
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e2223b8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   ShowAllBeaconList                   0x000000010d38ae90 -[MinewBeaconManager locationManager:didExitRegion:] + 128
    6   CoreLocation                        0x000000010e6a74e9 CLClientGetCapabilities + 38273
    7   CoreLocation                        0x000000010e699b55 CLClientInvalidate + 1051
    8   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e241b5c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 12
    9   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e226e54 __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 356
    10  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e226a23 __CFRunLoopRun + 1971
    11  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010e226016 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 406
    12  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000115f69a24 GSEventRunModal + 62
    13  UIKit                               0x000000010e7ee0d4 UIApplicationMain + 159
    14  ShowAllBeaconList                   0x000000010d37ccd7 main + 55
    15  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000111b0965d start + 1
    16  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Thanks

Comment: A `CLCircularRegion` doesn't have a `major` property; Only a `CLBeaconRegion` does.  If you enter a `CLCircularRegion` don't try and access its `major` property.

Comment: I am not accessing major property with CLCircular region, But I have CLBeaconRegions too. But did not understand that how it is using major property for circular region :(

Comment: Look at line 128 of `MinewBeaconManager` - that is where the access occurred.

Comment: MinewBeaconManager having only 67 lines :(

Comment: there are some CLBeaconRegion and one CLCircularRegion in my app, and I think they are clashing in between of them. Do we have any efficient way to handle different region on the same screen

Comment: That's not what the stack trace says; It crashed in your `locationManager:didExitRegion:` delegate method at line 128.  You need to confirm what type of region your are working with in the delegate method; Use conditional downcast

Comment: You should post the code for that delegate method

Comment: Agreed with @Paulw11 , plz post the delegate code as it clearly says you are trying to access the major property in the class somewhere. 
Please do a search in your xcode project to see where you are accessing the property

Comment: I suppose that is accessing in Framework which I have used. because I am not accessing major property

Comment: Set an exception breakpoint and it will show you where it is crashing.

Comment: It is showing exception in class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate

Answer (score 0):

When you respond to the -didEnterRegion and -didExitRegion you will want to make sure the CLRegion passed in is a specific class.

Objective-C

```
if ([region isKindOfClass:[CLCircularRegion class]]) {
    // Geofence
}
if ([region isKindOfClass:[CLBeaconRegion class]]) {
    // Beacon
}
```

Swift

```
if region is CLCircularRegion {
    // Geofence
}
if region is CLBeaconRegion {
    // Beacon
}
```

You will want to refrain from accessing any properties not available on the specific class. You can cast it to the specific object if you want the compiler to help you out.